# Better Solution for Finding ID Groups (Permutations/Combinations)

Tags: bash, shell-script, grep, math, permutations

My goal for this question is to find a more efficient solution to accomplish a task.

I have a file containing rows of IDs, e.g.:

```
1001 1004 1005 1010 1006 1020 1002
1002 1005 1006
1001 1010 1020 1043 1009 1016 1011 1012 1013
1010 1020 1030 1050 1004 1014 
1001 1008 1004 1021 1022 1010
1001 1004 1010
```

etc.

(*There are over 500K rows.)

From this list I created permutations of all possibly combinations of 2 IDs, 3 IDs, 4 IDs, 5 IDs, and 6 IDs.  From the 500K rows, over 50 million combinations of 2, 3, 4, 5, and 6 IDs were created.

The goal is to figure out how often IDs occur together.  For instance, how often 1001, 1004, and 1010 occur together.  Or how often 1010, 1020, 1030, 1040 occur together, etc.  Basically how often each combination of 2 IDs, 3 IDs, 4 IDs, 5 IDs, and 6 IDs occur together.

I wrote a Bash script (which is working) but it has been running for 3 days and I have realized is no where near being done.

My current script is reading each line in my permutations file (50 million records) and for each record is it reading how many IDs are in the permutation and then using awk:

(for a 3 ID combo):

```
awk '/'$id1'/ && /'$id2'/ && /'$id3'/' $filename
```

(for a 4 ID combo):

```
awk '/'$id1'/ && /'$id2'/ && /'$id3'/' && /'$id4'/' $filename
```

...and iterating through the 50 million combinations.  It it working at roughly 2-3 combos per second, but simple math will tell me that should take 200+ days.

Can anyone suggest a more efficient solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This goes more to programming, but I'd approach this by reading the file line-by-line, forming the combinations that are present on each line, counting their appearances in a hash table.

The part about forming the combinations is something that you'll want to use a library for.

Perl to the rescue, [Algorithm::Combinatorics](http://search.cpan.org/~fxn/Algorithm-Combinatorics-0.27/Combinatorics.pm) has a ready-made function for listing the combinations. Based on the examples, something like this seems pretty easy to make. This only counts combinations of two, feel free to improve it.

```
perl -MAlgorithm::Combinatorics=combinations -lane '
   $i = combinations([sort @F], 2); 
   while ($x = $i->next) { $count{join "-", @$x}++ }
   END {printf "%s: %d\n", $_, $count{$_} foreach keys %count  } 
   '  < ids > counts | sort -nk2 | tail -3
1010-1020: 3
1001-1010: 4
1004-1010: 4
```

I assumed the order of the numbers on each line didn't matter so I sorted the input. (I think `combinations` keeps the order of the elements, so the result doesn't have unsorted duplicates.)
  With the example numbers I got something like 30000 lines processed per second.

Comment: Thank you very much!  I have this working as needed.  I have not yet tested performance, but that will happen here in a bit.